# Save/Export Cocoa Project?

Tags: cocoa, export, save, project

How can I save/export my cocoa project so that I can send it over email to other computers that don't have xcode? I know it may not be necessary, but I would like to test my project on multiple computers. I right clicked my application in the dock, displayed it in finder, zipped it, and sent it, but did not open up on the computer that did not have xcode. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs:
[XCode: Buid and Archive](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/DistApps/DistApps.html)

The section you need is called Share Your Mac OS X Application with Others. Choose "Application" when you archive.

Comment: Hey I did exactly what it said, sent the package.pkg, and a zip of the application and neither could open on the computer. Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: I am guessing it is because you chose "Package" rather than "Application".

Comment: To clarify further, the extension should be .app

Comment: Oh so saving the application as an application, I should add that extension?

Comment: No, it will have the extension automatically. Did you choose application? Also, just to make sure, this isn't and iPhone app right? If it is an iPhone app then the steps are a little bit different.

Comment: No this is a mac app, but the extension did not add when i clicked share and chose share as application

Comment: Nevermind, I went to get info, and the extension IS .app, but it is just hidden. So its all good. The only problem is when I send the application over email, it has like an X through it, like this: http://www.google.com/imgres?q=smoking+is+bad&um=1&hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&biw=1352&bih=677&tbm=isch&tbnid=l5tRXPyu8ivJQM:&imgrefurl=http://doingood.glogster.com/why-smoking-is-bad/&docid=9upiyRAh7EVpRM&w=467&h=467&ei=MGxcTqOQFcPm0QHLr5jXAg&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=344&sqi=2&page=2&tbnh=164&tbnw=164&start=19&ndsp=18&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:19&tx=39&ty=67

Comment: Except not with a cigarette, and the application won't open

Comment: Ok, the application is fine. The problem is that email treats .app as a folder, so you can have problems when you attach it. to avoid those problems, ZIP the .app before you attach it.

Comment: So I zipped it and sent it, but it still can't open the application (the computer it was sent to). It still has that cross through it.

Comment: All I can tell you is to really read that document I linked to and make sure you follow it exactly. Also, make sure your app is built to run on whatever OS he is on (are you Developing on Lion and he is on Snow Leopard?), and check to make sure that you aren't signing the application with a dev cert. Also, when you create the .app can you open it on your computer?

Comment: Yes I'm sure I followed the steps correctly. I developed it on Lion, and sent it to a computer that has snow leopard. And yes when I create the .app, I can open it on my computer. Thanks!

Comment: If you can open it and they can't then you need to look at your build settings. Check the target OS. Check if you are signing the app with a dev cert. If those are ok then the problem lies with your friend. You are a programmer - you can figure this out.

Comment: I'll look into these things. I really do appreciate your help, and your right, I can figure this out! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending it to someone who has a Mac?  Then they can get Xcode for free if they sign up for a free developer account with Apple.

If they don't have a Mac, but you expect your code to be cross-platform to other operating systems, you'll need to write a Makefile.  To the best of my knowledge there is no way to do that other than writing it by hand.

The .xcodeproj document is a bundle, that is, a directory that contains a few text files.  The only really important one is project.pbxproj.  It's a plain text document, so in principle it would be straightforward to write a tool that translates it to a Makefile.  But I don't know about any existing tools that do that.

There's a good market opportunity for you. :)

Comment: Yes the computer is a mac. Is there not a way to send the app as a dmg so it can just run on a mac that does not have xcode? If you have to download xcode how is it possible to download applications from the internet that are mac based without having xcode? Thanks for the information by the way about the makefile, I was not familiar with that! :)

Comment: Do a release build of the application, put it in a folder then use Disk Utility to create the disk image: File->New->Disk Image from Folder.

Comment: If you are using Xcode 4, your built application will be in in /Users/YourName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName/Build/Products.  A quick way to get to it is to open the Products group in your Xcode project, Control-Click on the icon of your app, then select Show in Finder.